# How to: run a for loop over recurring row values in a column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

Image contains tibble of my dataframe.
10 values in "Cultivar" are repeated multiple times.
[image: DF]

I'd like to extract an lm for the associated values of each cultivar:
lm(data = df, DTT_mean ~ leaves_mean)

My initial code is

```
for(i in unique(nrow(df$Cultivar)){
    line <- lm(data = df[i], DTT_mean ~ leaves_mean)
    print(summary(line[i]))
}
```

The output should show the results of lm for all values of each cultivar. I could subset the df and then run the analysis on 10 new dfs, but there must be an easier way.

My error is: Error in `df[i]`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `nrow` is a single value and `unique` return just that value

Answer (score 1):

We may do a group by `lm`

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>%
   group_by(Cutivar) %>%
   summarise(out= list(tidy(lm(DTT_mean ~ leaves_mean, 
     data = cur_data()))), .groups= 'drop') %>%
   unnest(out)
```

Comment: Ah! I see the mistakes I made. This is very helpful.
Now that it is in list form, can I paste the values (slope, intercept, etc.) into a table?

Comment: @lettuce_guy you can use `tidy` to extract the components in a tibble and unnest it.  Updated